# Brightness, Contrast, Gamma adjustments with C++, Qt

Tags: c++, image-processing

What is the easiest way to **properly** adjust Brightness, Contrast and Gamma of an image. The word 'properly' is here because I know how to perform these adjustments improperly: loop over all the RGB pixels and do the following to each channel:

```
int changeBrightness( int value, int brightness) {
    return qBound<int>(0, value + brightness * 255 / 100, 255);
}
int changeContrast( int value, int contrast ) {
    return qBound<int>(0, int(( value - 127 ) * contrast / 100 ) + 127, 255 );
}
int changeGamma( int value, int gamma ) {
    return qBound<int>(0, int( pow( value / 255.0, 100.0 / gamma ) * 255 ), 255 );
}
```

Although this code will add the effect of brightness/conrast/gamma change, it does not look very well. Professional imaging software, like Photoshop does it much better.

What is the best library to deal with this kind of stuff? I know there is ImageMagick, but it's really heavy, I dont want to link to only one feature of hundreds. Are there any lightweight alternatives?

Comment: Photoshop may very well being doing something in addition to just basic bri/con/gamma adjustments, if it doesn't produce the same results as your implementation.  I'd vote for OpenCV however.

Comment: ImageMagick shows similar results to Photoshop. I think they both use a proper technique. I'm sure it's not rocket surgery, but still pretty complicated

Answer (score 2):

definetely [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/)

Comment: I was actually looking for something lightweight, choosing between OpenCV and ImageMagick, I'd go for the latter. Also, a link to the api that will do the above-mentioned adjustments will help

Comment: I think the 9 lines you posted are considerably more lightweight than any other solution you might come up with.. what's 'improper' about writing your own?

Comment: As I mentioned - it's seems improper to me because the same operation done in photoshop yeild images with much better quality.